# How to put border on <area>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to put a border around an `<area>` element?

I need to do this for testing an imagemap, but this doesn't work:

```css
area {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this plugin helps you http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight

Comment: That link's dead. Here's another: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're willing to use Javascript, add `mouseover/mouseout` event listeners to the `<area>` elements and `.focus()/.blur()`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Lwnf3/

Script:

```js
var areas = document.getElementsByTagName( 'area' );
for( var index = 0; index < areas.length; index++ ) {    
    areas[index].addEventListener( 'mouseover', function () {this.focus();}, false );
    areas[index].addEventListener( 'mouseout', function () {this.blur();}, false );
};
```

HTML:

```html
<img id="map" src="http://thinkingstiff.com/images/matt.jpg" usemap="#map"/>
<map name="map">
    <area shape="circle" coords="50,50,50" href="#" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="100,100,50" href="#" />
</map>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
    height: 245px;
    width: 180px;
}
```