# React How to add on hover border for <area> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, area

Currently I have image map on that I am plotting Area

Ex.

```
<img src="workplace.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap" width="400" height="379">
<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm">
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="phone.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Cup of coffee" href="coffee.htm">
</map>
```

once we hover the area how to add border around it.

following code works fine in **Javascript** but how can I do that in **React**.

[How to put border on <area>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634875/how-to-put-border-on-area)

```
var areas = document.getElementsByTagName( 'area' );
for( var index = 0; index < areas.length; index++ ) {    
    areas[index].addEventListener( 'mouseover', function () {this.focus();}, false );
    areas[index].addEventListener( 'mouseout', function () {this.blur();}, false );
};
```

Comment: Can you use CSS and just assign a classname/id to each area that is hoverable? You *could* use the mouse events but they are notoriously bad for this use-case, CSS is what you should strive to use.

Comment: @DrewReese It seems like the html area tag is not a visual element that we can style right?

Comment: I don't honestly know offhand, but it's a HTML tag, it should be targetable. Think you could create a small *running* codesandbox of your code we could inspect and debug in?

Comment: @DrewReese Sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write your js codes before return. And here`s a example for you

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Header() {
  useEffect(() => {
    function myFunction() {
      var areas = document.getElementsByTagName("area");
      for (var index = 0; index < areas.length; index++) {
        areas[index].addEventListener(
          "mouseover",
          function () {
            this.focus();
          },
          false
        );
        areas[index].addEventListener(
          "mouseout",
          function () {
            this.blur();
          },
          false
        );
      }
    }
    myFunction();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <img
        alt="img"
        id="map"
        src="http://thinkingstiff.com/images/matt.jpg"
        usemap="#map"
      />
      <map name="map">
        <area alt="area" shape="circle" coords="50,50,50" href="#" />
        <area alt="area" shape="circle" coords="100,100,50" href="#" />
      </map>
    </div>
  );
}
```